# Haskell/GHC: Matching multiple unary constructors with the same pattern

Tags: haskell, constructor, pattern-matching, ghc

So I was playing around with defining a TrieSet datatype (even though I know [I don't need to](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TrieMap)):

```
module Temp where

import Data.Map

data TrieSet a = Nonterminal (Data.Map a (TrieSet a)) | Terminal (Data.Map a (TrieSet a))

insert :: Ord a => [a] -> TrieSet a -> TrieSet a
insert [] (_ m) = Terminal m
insert (a:as) (c m) = c $ insertWith (insert as . flip const) a (insert as $ Nonterminal empty) m
```

When I got an error I've never seen before:

```
% ghc -c Temp.hs
Temp.hs:8:11: Parse error in pattern
```

So it seemed like GHC doesn't like matching multiple unary constructors with the same pattern.
I did another test to make sure that was the problem:

```
module Temp2 where

extract :: Either String String -> String
extract (_ s) = s
```

Which seemed to confirm my suspicion:

```
% ghc -c Temp2.hs
Temp2.hs:4:9: Parse error in pattern
```

So my question is (in multiple parts):

1. Am I right about why GHC doesn't like these functions?
2. Any reason why this wouldn't be a part of the Haskell standard?  After all, we can match multiple nullary constructors with the same pattern.
3. Is there a LANGUAGE pragma I can give GHC to make it accept these?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes. That kind of wildcards was never supported.
2. In my opinion, it would be much more difficult to infer a function's type if you don't know the data-constructor that was matched on. Just think about a function `f (_ n) = n`. What should be its type? The type-system of Haskell has no way to describe the arity of a type's constructors, so a function like `f` could not exist.
3. I don't think so.

Answer (score 8):

If it makes sense to match two or more constructors with a wildcard pattern, it probably also makes sense to unify those constructors and use an additional enumerated value to distinguish between them.

For example:

```
data Terminality = Terminal | Nonterminal
data TrieSet a = Node Terminality (Data.Map a (TrieSet a))

foo :: TrieSet X -> X
foo (Node _ m) = ...
```

If you don't want to make this change to your existing datatype, you could instead define a helper type and a corresponding helper function, and perform the conversion before you pattern-match.

```
data TreeSetView a = Node Terminality (Data.Map a (TrieSet a))

view :: TrieSet a => TreeSetView a
view (Terminal    m) = TreeSetView TerminalityTerminal    m
view (Nonterminal m) = TreeSetView TerminalityNonterminal m
```

Comment: +1, factoring out constructor cases like this is a very tidy solution that doesn't seem to get used as often as it could (another bonus is that "factoring out" is quite literally what's being done here).

Comment: +1 that makes a lot of sense. I, for one, definitely need to get more comfortable with this kind of data type refactoring.