# Pattern matching on a Haskell function with type variable

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

In Haskell, is it possible to pattern match on functions that have a type variable for the outer but not inner type? Here, for example, funky takes any type constructor that takes a `Bar`. While this works for destructuring the two cases, I'm not sure how to write the global case on the bottom, which should ideally return the result of the destructuring. I've put a question mark before `q` because that's what's stumping me - I'm not sure how to destructure that last pattern match to get the `Bar` out. Thanks in advance for your help!

```hs
data Bar = Bar
data Foo = AA Bar | BB Bar | CC Bar | DD Bar

funky :: x Bar -> Bar
funky (AA z) = z
funky (BB z) = z
funky (? q) = q
```

Comment: Can you provide more context on what your actual goal is? This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992).

Comment: Apart from the little confusion about type constructors vs data constructors, this is a duplicate of: [Can I match a data constructor wildcard in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158110/can-i-match-a-data-constructor-wildcard-in-haskell). I also don't know why this was downvoted, since the linked question doesn't provide much more, and has 11 upvotes.

Comment: Also related: [Haskell/GHC: Matching multiple unary constructors with the same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131954/haskell-ghc-matching-multiple-unary-constructors-with-the-same-pattern).

Comment: @MikaelF I’m pretty sure those aren’t duplicates: those are asking about pattern matching multiple constructors of a single type at once, whereas this is asking about pattern matching on a single constructor but with a type variable. (At least, that was my interpretation of the question; I could be wrong.)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I am creating a state machine using `quickcheck-state-machine` for a legacy API that takes one argument of type `Request`. So the state machine has commands ie `data Command = Start Request | Stop Request | Query Request`. Sometimes, I want to write a function that transforms the request independent of the state. So what it looks like this means is that I either need to do one command `data Command = Command Request` or, if I use `Stop` `Start` etc, do pattern matching for every function that uses a `Command` even if the way it treats the `Request` is the same.

Comment: @Mike To solve this, couldn’t you just write a function `transform :: (Request -> Request) -> Command -> Command` to handle the pattern matching, and then just use that? You could go further with this and define `data Command' a = Start a | Stop a | Query a` and then say `type Command = Command' Request`; then `Command` becomes a functor which you can map over (so `transform` is equivalent to `fmap`).

Comment: Great minds think alike, that is what I wound up doing :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t pattern-match on a function with a type variable on the outside. To see why, let’s look at your code:

```hs
data Bar = Bar
data Foo = AA Bar | BB Bar | CC Bar | DD Bar

funky :: x Bar -> Bar
```

The type signature for `funky` states that it takes a value of type `x Bar` and returns a value of type `Bar`. Importantly, it can do this for *any* type `x` of the appropriate kind — that’s what a type variable means.

Now, to see the problem with this, consider this type:

```hs
data Ignore a = Ignored
```

That is, for any type `a`, there is only one value of type `Ignore a`, and that value is `Ignored`.

So using this type, if we take `x ~ Ignore`, then `funky` becomes `funky :: Ignore Bar -> Bar`. The problem here should be obvious: there is no value of type `Bar` stored in `Ignore Bar`! So there’s no way to pattern-match on `Ignore Bar` and get out a `Bar`. And hence there is no way in general to write a function `funky :: x Bar -> Bar` which does what you want.